# Add CSS minifier to Sprockets

Tags: ruby, yui, rack, sprockets

I have a web application which uses rack.

The code:

```
set :assets, (Sprockets::Environment.new { |env|
    env.js_compressor = Uglifier.new({
      :output => {
        :preserve_line => true,
        :bracketize => true,
        :beautify => true,
        :indent_level => 4,
        :semicolons => true,
      },
      :mangle => false
  })

  env.append_path(APP_ROOT + "/app/assets/images")
  env.append_path(APP_ROOT + "/app/assets/javascripts")
  env.append_path(APP_ROOT + "/app/assets/stylesheets")
})
```

I now want to add a CSS minifier to it.

1. Can someone explain why only javascript files are taken into the JS compressor above?
2. Can I add something like *env.css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new()* after the  JS_compressor to get my requirement done

**UPDATE: Well the second actually worked. But I have no clue how it worked :)**

Answer (score 0):

You hadn't set up the Sprockets::Environment.css_compressor variable, so there was no compressor available to run on `text/css` assets.

```
puts Sprockets::Environment.methods.inspect
#=> [...#css_compressor, #css_compressor=, #js_compressor, #js_compressor=,...]
```

To answer your question about how assets are loaded, yes the default is to point to one load path and you can as well manipulate that to include others.
https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets

> The load path is an ordered list of directories that Sprockets uses to
>   search for assets. To add a directory to your environment's load path, use the append_path and prepend_path methods.

Comment: Thanks. Sprockets::Environment.new () section in my code encompasses the  js_compressor as well as append paths (which includes JS/CSS&images). Does the JS_compressor knows which files to work on. I was using something like below and it worked. Is this the correct way of doing it.  `set :assets, (Sprockets::Environment.new { |env|
    env.js_compressor = Uglifier.new({
      :mangle => true
  }) env.css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new()
  env.append_path(APP_ROOT + "/app/assets/javascripts")
  env.append_path(APP_ROOT + "/app/assets/stylesheets")
})`

Comment: Yes, sprockets uses the load path to handle which assets to compress.